# How do I fix the multiple errors that I'm facing on Atom with the Atom linter?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, atom-editor

I'm on Atom and my interface is currently displaying this:

{Error running gjslint}(x4)
{Error running selective}(x4)

When I opened up the errors section, here's what I found:

```
[Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running gjslint Error: Failed to spawn command `gjslint`. Make sure `gjslint` is installed and on your PATH
    at VM310 helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @ /Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter/dist/index.js:1
linter-registry.ts:133 [Linter] Error running selective Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:342)
    at fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542)
    at module.exports (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/rehype/rehype.js:14)
    at Object.lint (/Users/Timothy/.atom/packages/linter-selective/node_modules/@selective/atom/atom.js:19)
    at linter-registry.ts:107
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bt.lint (linter-registry.ts:103)
```

All of them have appeared as soon as I started to work on a new document with the Atom linter installed with its associated specifics. How, then, do I go about remedying these errors?

Comment: read the errors, `gjslint` is not installed and `/Users/Timothy/Documents/config.selective` is not found. Perhaps fix or remove some linting addon/plugin you have added

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark icon. This will help others find a working solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [linter-gjslint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-gjslint#gjslint-installation) package has a dependency on `gjslint` that needs to be installed separately, as mentioned in the documentation:

> Before using this plugin, you must ensure that gjslint is installed on your system. To install gjslint, read [this](https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto).

This is a common practice among most linter packages
across different editors.